# Why does toggle happen only once in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, I need to toggle a class on some buttons and I don't really understand how to do it more than once. The problem is with the second block of code (the one with document.querySelector), not with the other one.

The other one is there because it is used for navigation, and it has to be there.

If you click on "executie", the text will change. Below it, there will be an arrow to change the text. It works, but if you want to turn back (on the other arrow that appears) it doesn't work anymore.

Can anybody help me understand why that happens? Thanks.

```js
document.querySelector(".fa-arrow-custom").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const primaPagina = document.querySelector(".executie-problema");
  const aDouaPagina = document.querySelector(".executie2-problema")
  primaPagina.classList.toggle("hide", !primaPagina.classList.contains("hide"));
  aDouaPagina.classList.toggle("hide", !aDouaPagina.classList.contains("hide"));
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6612084f00.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="executie-problema problema">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
              Pasi (Divide):
<ol class="pasi-executie">
  <li>In main este apelata functia, cu n=5.</li>
  <li>Pt n=5, factorial returneaza 5*factorial(4). Astfel, este pus in stiva 5*factorial(4).</li>
  <li>Se calculeaza factorial(4), ce returneaza 4*factorial(3), urmatorul element din stiva devenind 4*factorial(3).</li>
  <li>Se calculeaza factorial(3), ce returneaza 3*factorial(2), care este pus si in stiva.</li>
  <li>Factorial(2) este 2*factorial(1) – se pune in continuare in stiva.</li>
  <li>Factorial(1) este 1*factorial(0) – ultimul element pus in stiva.</li>
  <li>Divizarea se opreste, deoarece factorial(0) este 1.</li>
  <li>Datorita faptului ca in stiva ultimul element se pune intotdeauna deasupra, aceasta arata astfel:</li>
</ol>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-arrow-custom"></i>
            </div>
          </div>                   
    </div>
    <div class="executie2-problema problema hide">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          Urmatorul pas (Impera):
<ol class="pasi-executie">
<li>Factorial(0) este 1, deci 1*factorial(0) este 1.</li>
<li>2*factorial(1) este 2*1=2.</li>
<li>3*factorial(2) este 3*2=6</li>
<li>4*factorial(3) este 4*6=24</li>
<li>5*factorial(4) este 5*24=120 <- care este problema initiala, deci raspunsul este 120.</li>
</ol>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-arrow-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>                   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="./js/meniu-introducere.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) takes two parameters; the class to toggle, and a Boolean of whether to force the toggle to take place. Without the second parameter, it will add the class if it does not exist, and remove it if it does. The second set of `toggle` calls do not need the second parameter specified.

Comment: @KooiInc I removed the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it doesn't work

Comment: ... My comment was a statement of fact. There is nothing to "work" or not...

Comment: @HereticMonkey "The second set of toggle calls do not need the second parameter specified" - it didn't work because I misunderstood it. That was the answer indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `querySelectorAll` if there two or more elements.

then use `forEach` to add an event for each element

```js
document.getElementById("listUL").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const id = tgt.dataset.id;
    [...document.querySelectorAll("div.problema")]
    .forEach(div => div.classList.toggle("hide", !div.classList.contains(id)))
  })

const primaPagina = document.querySelector(".executie-problema");
const aDouaPagina = document.querySelector(".executie2-problema");

document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-custom").forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    primaPagina.classList.toggle("hide", !primaPagina.classList.contains("hide"));
    aDouaPagina.classList.toggle("hide", !aDouaPagina.classList.contains("hide"));
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Divide et Impera</title>
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/fonts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6612084f00.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
          <div class="container-meniu">
            <ul class="list-group" id="listUL">
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom generalitati" data-id="generalitati-problema">Generalitati</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom avantaje" data-id="avantaje-problema">Avantaje</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom avantaje" data-id="dezavantaje-problema">Dezavantaje</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom identificare" data-id="identificare-problema">Identificare DEI</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom criterii" data-id="criterii-problema">Criterii de rezolvare DEI</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom de-ce-dei" data-id="de-ce-dei-problema">De ce DEI?</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom cod" data-id="cod-problema">Cod</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom complexitate" data-id="complexitate-problema">Complexitate</li>
                <li class="list-group-flush list-item-custom executie" data-id="executie-problema">Executie</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="generalitati-problema problema">
                test
      </div>
      <div class="executie-problema problema hide">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
              Pasi (Divide):
<ol class="pasi-executie">
  <li>In main este apelata functia, cu n=5.</li>
  <li>Pt n=5, factorial returneaza 5*factorial(4). Astfel, este pus in stiva 5*factorial(4).</li>
  <li>Se calculeaza factorial(4), ce returneaza 4*factorial(3), urmatorul element din stiva devenind 4*factorial(3).</li>
  <li>Se calculeaza factorial(3), ce returneaza 3*factorial(2), care este pus si in stiva.</li>
  <li>Factorial(2) este 2*factorial(1) – se pune in continuare in stiva.</li>
  <li>Factorial(1) este 1*factorial(0) – ultimul element pus in stiva.</li>
  <li>Divizarea se opreste, deoarece factorial(0) este 1.</li>
  <li>Datorita faptului ca in stiva ultimul element se pune intotdeauna deasupra, aceasta arata astfel:</li>
</ol>
<img src="./img/stivaDAC.jpg" alt="" srcset="" class="img-custom-introducere">
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-arrow-custom"></i>
            </div>
          </div>                   
    </div>
    <div class="executie2-problema problema hide">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-custom">
          Urmatorul pas (Impera):
<ol class="pasi-executie">
<li>Factorial(0) este 1, deci 1*factorial(0) este 1.</li>
<li>2*factorial(1) este 2*1=2.</li>
<li>3*factorial(2) este 3*2=6</li>
<li>4*factorial(3) este 4*6=24</li>
<li>5*factorial(4) este 5*24=120 <- care este problema initiala, deci raspunsul este 120.</li>
</ol>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-arrow-custom"></i>
        </div>
      </div>                   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="./js/meniu-introducere.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep. That was the answer. Thanks :)